# Issues defining a variable for shared preferences username

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently testing and trying out a new settings page for a Flutter application. I'm new to Flutter so I was following along with a tutorial, however I got an error that the tutorial video didn't have through VS Code which says:

> The named parameter 'username' isn't defined.
> Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'username'.dartundefined_named_parameter

and

> The parameter 'username' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.dartmissing_default_value_for_parameter

Which VS Code underlined the "username" variable in red in both files (lines 217 and 8 respectively). I was testing around with the variable and look up solutions online, but I couldn't find an incredibly simple solution that I understood. I'm sorry if this a very simple issue, but I am new to Flutter and don't understand what's wrong. Thank you for your time.

The overall goal of the code is to save the username and display it in other pages.

**main.dart File (Lines 148 - 222)**

```
// Settings Page & Account Information
class Settings extends StatelessWidget {
  Settings({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? 'DarkTheme'
        : 'LightTheme';

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Settings'), actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                _saveSettings;
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
              tooltip: 'Save Settings')
        ]),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 8),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                // Account
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 0, 0),
                      child: Text('Account Information',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                          ))),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 12),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _usernameController,
                      inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(25)],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Username',
                        labelText: 'Username',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  // App Settings
                  children: [
                    // SwitchListTile(value: DarkMode, onChanged: Light => Dark => Light)
                    // ChangeThemeButtonWidget(),
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: _saveSettings,
                        child: const Text('Save Settings'))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }

  void _saveSettings() {
    final newSettings = Settings(
      username: _usernameController.text,
    );

    print(newSettings);
  }
}
```

**saved_data.dart File**

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:bit/main.dart';

class Settings {
  final String username;

  Settings({
    this.username,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using different name for both classes. Also, for 2nd Settings class the message is clear:

> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.dartmissing_default_value_for_parameter

so, Settings become:

```
class SettingsModel {
  final String username;

  SettingsModel({
    required this.username,
  });
}
```

and, Settings should be:

```
void _saveSettings() {
    final newSettings = SettingsModel(
      username: _usernameController.text,
    );
  }
```